# After converting an HLS M3U8 into an MP4, how to find out if there were TS segments missing, originally?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8, transport-stream

I have a few `.ts` files and the corresponding `index.m3u8` file which looks something like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:15
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:3.170,
seg-1-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:3.170,
seg-2-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:3.170,
seg-3-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:3.170,
seg-4-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:3.170,
seg-5-v1-a1.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

So, to convert it into a single `output.mp4` file, I ran the following command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i index.m3u8 -c copy output.mp4
...
[hls @ 0x55d78a3a6280] Opening 'seg-1-v1-a1.ts' for reading
...
[hls @ 0x55d78a3a6280] Opening 'seg-2-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x55d78a3a6280] Opening 'seg-3-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x55d78a3a6280] Opening 'seg-4-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x55d78a3a6280] Opening 'seg-5-v1-a1.ts' for reading
...
```

Afterwards, I removed the `.ts` files and the `index.m3u8` and just kept `output.mp4`. However, as it turns out, I did not have all the `.ts` files and the output was originally more like this:

```
$ rm seg-3-v1-a1.ts
$ ffmpeg -i index.m3u8 -c copy output.mp4
...
[hls @ 0x5555d0d86280] Opening 'seg-1-v1-a1.ts' for reading
...
[hls @ 0x5555d0d86280] Opening 'seg-2-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x5555d0d86280] Opening 'seg-3-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x5555d0d86280] Failed to open segment 3 of playlist 0
[hls @ 0x5555d0d86280] Opening 'seg-4-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x5555d0d86280] Opening 'seg-5-v1-a1.ts' for reading
...
```

When watching the video, at the position of the missing segment, the picture freezes for a few seconds, then the video continues. I have a few `.mp4` files and I want to find out which of them are affected by this issue. Without having the original log, how can I find out if there were any segments missing when I ran the `ffmpeg -i index.m3u8 -c copy output.mp4` command?

I found one command at https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4 which unfortunately doesn't find any issues:

```
$ ffmpeg -v error -i output.mp4 -f null -
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: I would `ffprobe -show_packets` and for each stream extract `dts`, `pts` and `duration` fields of each packet. If there are any gaps, it means a segment was missing. Not sure if that will work, though.

Comment: Please provide a sample MP4 file.

Comment: @user3840170 Hey thanks for the idea, I've just looked into it and I cannot make much sense of the values though. There seem to be gaps in any case, in both proper and defective output - doesn't matter if I delete a segment or not.

Comment: @finefoot Gaps in the sense that the [pts, pts+duration) intervals, taken together, don’t form a connected line?

Comment: @user3840170 Exactly. Here is a short Python script that I wrote to do that: https://anonpaste.org/?a1b9b4d19ba77500#A3FjjxB6jhGxFXWbRu1Mwz2wm4RCMsb333PrPYiWyeKu There are 2 gaps in dts and lots of misalignment in pts

Comment: And here is the script how to get my exemplary proper.mp4 and defective.mp4 files: https://anonpaste.org/?72db65d1ef8ccab7#32KcXzMVPx359jwWs6ounvcwdRDoFMTFe6yqKAwRnDeL

Comment: @user3840170 Does pts[n+1] *always* have to equal pts[n]+duration? And dts? Sometimes I even have negative values for the first packet...

Answer (score 1):

You can check if r_frame_rate and avg_frame_rate are equal.
The command below:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_streams output.mp4 | grep "frame_rate"
```

will output (for correct file) something like this:

> r_frame_rate=24/1 
> avg_frame_rate=24/1

and (for corrupted file) something like this:

> r_frame_rate=24/1 
> avg_frame_rate=886/37

This method is not perfect, but in many cases should be totally fine.

---

Second method, intuitive and in my honest opinion working only in specific conditions, is looking for freezes. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf "freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=2" -f null - 1>/dev/null 2>&1 \
| grep "duration"
```

It can work, but only if stream is really specific.

---

Another method, similar to the first one, is looking for VFR.
The command:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf vfrdet -an -f null -
```

will output:

> [Parsed_vfrdet_0 @ 0x55563547bf00] VFR:0.000094 (2/21261) min: 3750 max: 183750 avg: 93750

for corrupted file. For correct it will be:

> [Parsed_vfrdet_0 @ 0x564c33d53140] VFR:0.000000 (0/21311)

This is similar to the first method, but contrary to appearances – different!
As far as I know, it is possible to have equal `r_frame_rate` and `avg_frame_rate`, while VFR is not zero!

In my honest opinion checking VFR is the best option and may work. That's bad you didn't provide any example file. I assume that your stream should've VFR:0.000000, but that's reading tea leaves.

As far as I know, there is no universal method to do what you need. I hope any of my examples will fit, but it really depends and need to be tested in practice, on the right files. Exactly these, which you want to check.

---

According to your reply below my answer, I have implemented simple script that's:

1. downloading ts files
2. converting these to correct mp4
3. corrupting one of the ts files
4. converting these (with missing ts file) to corrupted mp4
5. testing each mp4 file using my first method (comparing r_frame_rate == avg_frame_rate)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Blender demo movie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintel
# Full URL: https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8

bURL=https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/video/

# I'm checking each available bitrate. You can modify that.
bitratesArray=("250" "500" "800" "1100" "1500" "4000" "6000" "10000")

# Here you can choose which ts file you want to remove from
# the ffmpeg conversion (it'll be temporary renamed, doesn't matter).
tsToCorrupt="14"

for i in ${bitratesArray[@]}
do
  # Download all files.
  # To be nice, I'm preventing unnecessary server load.
  if [ ! -d "${i}kbit" ]
  then
    echo -e "\nDownloading ${i}kbit version"
        
    curl "${bURL}${i}kbit.m3u8" | tee -a "${i}kbit.m3u8" | grep '\.ts' | \
    sed -e "s|^|$bURL|g" -e "s/\.ts/\.ts /g" > "${i}kbit_fullURL.m3u8"
        
    aria2c -q -c -j 16 -x 16 -d "${i}kbit" -i"${i}kbit_fullURL.m3u8"
    echo -e "\n"
  fi
    
  # Convert proper
  echo "Converting: ${i}kbit_proper.mp4" 
  ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel error \
  -i "${i}kbit.m3u8" -c copy "${i}kbit_proper.mp4" 
    
  # Make temporal source defect
  mv "${i}kbit/seq-${tsToCorrupt}.ts" "${i}kbit/seq-${tsToCorrupt}.ts_CORRUPTED"
    
  # Convert defective
  echo "Converting: ${i}kbit_defective.mp4" 
  ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel error \
  -i "${i}kbit.m3u8" -c copy "${i}kbit_defective.mp4" 
    
  # Repair defected source (obviously converted file is still corrupted)
  mv "${i}kbit/seq-${tsToCorrupt}.ts_CORRUPTED" "${i}kbit/seq-${tsToCorrupt}.ts"
done

# Examine generated files
echo -e "\n\nREPORT"
for i in *.mp4
do
  echo -e "\n---------------------------\nFilename: \n${i}"

  report=$(ffprobe -v error -show_streams $i | grep "frame_rate")

  echo -e "\ncalculated frame rates:\n${report}"
    echo -e "\nVerdict: \nFile ${i} is "

  echo ${report} | \
  awk -F'[=\n ]' ' { if ( $2 == $4 ) { print "OK" } else { print "WRONG" }; } ' 
done
```

For me it's working fine.

Comment: Ha, thank you so much for writing an answer :) I like the idea with the frame rate. However, VFR doesn't work: it shows non-zero values for both files - doesn't matter if proper or defective.

Comment: I did provide a script to generate two example files: https://anonpaste.org/?72db65d1ef8ccab7#32KcXzMVPx359jwWs6ounvcwdRDoFMTFe6yqKAwRnDeL

Comment: Any idea why the VFR check fails? Any idea how to make `ffprobe -show_packets` with dts, pts and duration work?

Comment: @finefoot Interesting... even more, because we were working on the same files! Just different bitrates. According to your script, I've prepared simple script to check my first method. It works well. For consistency and to make it persistent (for other users) I'll paste it to my main answer.

Comment: @finefoot Ok, I've just updated my answer. Check the script, please.

Comment: Sure, like I said, checking the frame rate is a good idea and I had already verified that. :) By the way, I also found that some videos don't match exactly, like 1e-5 difference in r and avg frame rates. And what about VFR? Why does it fail? And why does `ffprobe -show_packets` with dts, pts and duration not work? Any ideas on that?